# Search query on fieldvalue varchar ('SUM-123') in elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I am trying to search for a document in elasticsearch.

Field name is `sum` and Field value is `'SUM-123'`

I created a bool query to `matchQuery('sum','SUM-123')`.

But it is not returning the exact sum field documents instead it is returning the documents with different field values.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to do an exact string matching, you should not `analyzed` your index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do an exact string matching, you should not `analyzed` your index.

More info [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html)